# How to use css selector instead of xpath in appium 1.2.2 version for ios application

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I want to click inside collectioncell and i have inspected the xpath as

```
//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[3]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[3]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]")).click();`
```

but the above xpath is not working for me. I am using Appium1.2.2 version in mac. How to modify the above xpath in terms of css selector?.

Comment: The best tutorial is here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Comment: @Priyanshu - Thanks for the link but my question is related to appium , and css selector use is quite different here. i just need a way to get the child elements "UIACollectionCell" from the Parent element "UIACollectionView[1]"

Answer (score 3):

It's likely not your XPath. Appium + IOS + XPath is known to have issues. I suggest you use the UIAutomation part of my answer, but I also provided an alternative XPath solution which may work.

---

In Appium there is no concept of "CSS Selector". Native Apps are not written in HTML.

The closest solution to `By.cssSelector` would be to do:

```
By.className("UIACollectionCell")
```

However, that would give you all collection cells, regardless of if they belonged to multiple parent `UIACollectionView`s. That's not what we want.

### **We want to find all child elements relative to a single parent element**

So the locator strategy you need needs to be able to filter elements relative to a parent element. We have two options: XPath and UIAutomation

#### XPath

```
value = "//UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell"
collectionCells = driver.findElement(By.xpath(value);
```

#### UIAutomation

The benefit is that [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) is native, quick, and reliable. XPath will sometimes give you completely different elements, or Instruments will just flake out and crash.

I am assuming you are not using Appium's [Java Client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) library. To use the [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) locator strategy, you need to use Appium's [Java Client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) library.

With the [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) locator strategy, we would solve your problem like so:

```
value = ".collectionViews()[0].cells()"
collectionCells = driver.findElementsByIosUIAutomation(value)
```

Comment: the link for UIAutomation is not working anymore. Can you update it?